# Re-render issue in React Native

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I can't figure out why this screen is re-rendering infinitely, the function worked on a previous page and I copied it over, but now none of the cases work. This is my first time using React Native coming from only Javascript in HTML so I don't quite understand the basic fundamentals yet.

It has something to do with the workout state but I don't know what is wrong.

GeneratedWorkoutScreen.js

```
import React, { useState, useContext } from "react";
import { View, Text, StyleSheet, TouchableOpacity, Alert } from "react-native";
import data from "./../moves.json";
import GlobalSkillState from "./../contexts/GlobalSkillLevel";
import * as firebase from "firebase";
import Generate from "./../big_functions/generate";
import { render } from "react-dom";
import SkillLevel from "../big_functions/SkillLevel";
import { BaseRouter } from "@react-navigation/native";
import { getAppLoadingLifecycleEmitter } from "expo/build/launch/AppLoading";

export default class GeneratedWorkoutScreen extends React.Component {
  Generated = () => {
    const [workout, setWorkout] = useState("");
    const [state, setState] = useContext(GlobalSkillState);
    const shuffle = (arr) => {
      var i, j, temp;
      for (i = arr.length - 1; i > 0; i--) {
        j = Math.floor(Math.random() * (i + 1));
        temp = arr[i];
        arr[i] = arr[j];
        arr[j] = temp;
      }
      return arr;
    };
    const test = 0;
    switch (test) {
      case 0:
        // //  warm up
        // const warmup =
        //   "\nWarm up \n\n" +
        //   data.moves.warmup[0] +
        //   "                   " +
        //   data.timeIntervals[5] +
        //   "\n" +
        //   data.moves.warmup[1] +
        //   "           " +
        //   data.timeIntervals[10];

        // //  training 1
        // const qwer1 = [0, 1, 2, 3];
        // const qwer2 = shuffle(qwer1);

        // const temp1 = [1, 1, 1, 1];
        // const begRanNumber = temp1.map(
        //   (x) =>
        //     10 * Math.floor(Math.random() * 1 + 1) +
        //     5 * Math.floor(Math.random() * 4 + 0)
        // );

        // const temp3 = [0, 1, 2, 3];
        // const simpBegWorkout = temp3.map(
        //   (x) => begRanNumber[x] + " " + data.moves.basic[qwer2[x]] + "\n"
        // );

        // //  training 2
        // const comboBegWorkout = data.moves.beginnerCombos.map(
        //   (x) =>
        //     "\n" +
        //     data.moves.beginnerCombos[
        //       Math.floor(Math.random() * data.moves.beginnerCombos.length + 0)
        //     ] +
        //     "         5 Minutes"
        // );
        // //  render
        // const workout =
        //   "\n\nWorkout \n\n" +
        //   simpBegWorkout[0] +
        //   simpBegWorkout[1] +
        //   simpBegWorkout[2] +
        //   simpBegWorkout[3] +
        //   comboBegWorkout[0];
        // setWorkout(warmup + workout);
        setWorkout("hello");
        break;

      case 1:
        Alert.alert("intermediate");
        setWorkout("");
        break;

      case 2:
        Alert.alert("advanced");
        setWorkout("");
        break;

      default:
        Alert.alert("Please select your skill level" + workout);
        break;
    }

    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <Text style={styles.genList}>{workout}</Text>
      </View>
    );
  };

  render() {
    return <this.Generated></this.Generated>;
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    justifyContent: "center",
    alignItems: "center",
  },
  genList: {
    flex: 1,
    justifyContent: "flex-start",
    alignItems: "flex-start",
  },
});
```

Comment: Get rid of ‘ return <this.Generated></this.Generated>‘ and make Generated be its own function component.  You cannot call hooks inside of a class component.

Comment: It's not the problem anyway, but yes, don't mix both worlds of creating React components

Comment: Okay thanks for the tip I will keep that in mind. However the re-render issue is still occurring even after doing that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are kind of mixing both methods of creating a React component, class-based and functional based. I would recommend the last one for different reasons.

Now, regarding your question, this is causing your component to re-render infinitely:

```
const test = 0;
    switch (test) {
      case 0:
        // //  warm up
        // const warmup =
        //   "\nWarm up \n\n" +
        //   data.moves.warmup[0] +
        //   "                   " +
        //   data.timeIntervals[5] +
        //   "\n" +
        //   data.moves.warmup[1] +
        //   "           " +
        //   data.timeIntervals[10];

        // //  training 1
        // const qwer1 = [0, 1, 2, 3];
        // const qwer2 = shuffle(qwer1);

        // const temp1 = [1, 1, 1, 1];
        // const begRanNumber = temp1.map(
        //   (x) =>
        //     10 * Math.floor(Math.random() * 1 + 1) +
        //     5 * Math.floor(Math.random() * 4 + 0)
        // );

        // const temp3 = [0, 1, 2, 3];
        // const simpBegWorkout = temp3.map(
        //   (x) => begRanNumber[x] + " " + data.moves.basic[qwer2[x]] + "\n"
        // );

        // //  training 2
        // const comboBegWorkout = data.moves.beginnerCombos.map(
        //   (x) =>
        //     "\n" +
        //     data.moves.beginnerCombos[
        //       Math.floor(Math.random() * data.moves.beginnerCombos.length + 0)
        //     ] +
        //     "         5 Minutes"
        // );
        // //  render
        // const workout =
        //   "\n\nWorkout \n\n" +
        //   simpBegWorkout[0] +
        //   simpBegWorkout[1] +
        //   simpBegWorkout[2] +
        //   simpBegWorkout[3] +
        //   comboBegWorkout[0];
        // setWorkout(warmup + workout);
        setWorkout("hello");
        break;

      case 1:
        Alert.alert("intermediate");
        setWorkout("");
        break;

      case 2:
        Alert.alert("advanced");
        setWorkout("");
        break;

      default:
        Alert.alert("Please select your skill level" + workout);
        break;
    }
```

Since `Generated` is a functional component, every time it re-renders for whatever reason, it executes the above code again, hence, updating the state of `workout` again, and so on...

If you just want to execute that code in specific cases or only 1 time when your component renders, use `useEffect` ([more info here](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html))

Comment: Ahh I get it now, thank you so much! What is the reason for the that to happen when I don't use ```useEffect```? also is it bad to have a setState inside a useEffect?

Comment: Hmm i just realised, after using ```useEffect``` it still renders an infinite amount of time but the ```useEffect``` is just stopping it. I get a warning that says "Maximum update depth exceeded"

Comment: That's happening because every time a component re-renders, that functional component is called so all the code inside that function is executed. How do you implemented the useEffect? If you want it to happen just one time when it first renders, use `useEffect(() => { /* code */}, [])`

Comment: got it! Thank you so much!!

Comment: No worries at all! Keep it up